# r.sun model crashing (GRASS GIS 7.0.4, Windows 7 Enterprise SP1)

Tags: windows-7, grass-7.0, grass-6.4

I have been trying to run the r.sun model on a small test area but it crashes after roughly 5-6 minutes. A windows error pops up saying the program stopped working. I used it before to create an incidence angle raster map with no issue and r.horizon runs fine with the same inputs. Does anyone have a suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?

This is the code I use to run the model:

```
r.sun elevation=DEM@User aspect=Aspect@User slope=Slope@User horizon_basename=horangle horizon_step=11.25 glob_rad=Global day=15 step=1
```

After I click the windows prompt to close the running script it prompts me that the command is finished but it procuded no output. Below is a screenshot of the issues.

[image]

Comment: Issue is fixed with help of the following post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71919/solar-irradiation-calculation-using-r-sun. It was the case that my layers were of different sizes. I thought it was fine by using the DEM, which set the boundaries of the sample area, as a mask. Though I had to set g.region to do so apparrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is fixed with the help of the following post: [Solar irradiation calculation using r.sun](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71919/solar-irradiation-calculation-using-r-sun).

It was the case that my layers had different sizes. I thought it was fine by using the DEM, which set the boundaries of the sample area, as a mask. Though I had to set g.region to do so apparrently.